# unable to fetch selected row data from jsp to servlet using hidden element

Tags: html, jsp, post

I want to perform CURD operation using JSP,servlet and Mysql . Trying to post id using hidden element but when i perform delete operation it always deleted the first row in the table.
Please let me know how to post selected data to servlet data using single form through hidden element.

```
<c:forEach var="record" items="${SLIST}">   
        <input type="hidden" value="${record.Id}" id="poststudentId" name="poststudentId" />
            <td>${record.Id</td>
            <td>${record.lastName}</td>
           
            <td><input type="submit"  value="View"    id="view_button"  name="option" class="view" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit"  value="Edit"    id="edit_button1"  name="option" class="Edit" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit"  value="Delete"  id="delete_button" name="option" class="Delete" /></td>

        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken literally, this appears to need an HTML `<form>` tag surrounding the `<input>` elements, otherwise it can't relate them together.